# Register Access in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, embedded

I was trying to implement this approach of accessing registers: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/register-access-in-c/184401954?pgno=2

This is a sample code: In this example, I am trying to create two Register base - UART and PWM. Both have their set of Registers (with offset from the base address).
Base address is mocked for testing purpose.

**Question 1**: The article does not mention in detail about the way to handle multiple device and is my implementation the right understanding? if so

**Question 2** Is there a way to avoid duplicate code - regWrite, regRead and regAddress functions ?
So Ideally, I would like to just define namespace with base address and enum Registers and reuse the access functions.What is the best way of achieving this ?

I get compilation error with regWrite, regRead, regAddress outside namespaces. It is not able to recognize Registers, baseAddress.

**NOTE**:I am writing code for a 2k RAM controller with a RTOS running on top of it. So I am also interested in keeping the code size and execution time relatively low but still improve readability.

```
namespace UART{
enum Registers {
    STATUS = 0, RESET = 1
};

unsigned int fakeBase[2];
unsigned int baseAddress = (unsigned int)(&fakeBase);

inline volatile unsigned int *regAddress(Registers Reg){
    return reinterpret_cast<volatile unsigned int *> (baseAddress + Reg);
}
inline void regWrite(Registers Reg, unsigned int value){
    *regAddress(Reg) = value;
}

inline volatile unsigned int regRead(Registers Reg){
    return *regAddress(Reg);
}
}


namespace PWM{
enum Registers {
    DCA = 0, DCB = 1, DCC = 2
};

unsigned int fakeBase[3];
unsigned int baseAddress = (unsigned int)(&fakeBase);

inline volatile unsigned int *regAddress(Registers Reg){
    return reinterpret_cast<volatile unsigned int *> (baseAddress + Reg);
}
inline void regWrite(Registers Reg, unsigned int value){
    *regAddress(Reg) = value;
}

inline volatile unsigned int regRead(Registers Reg){
    return *regAddress(Reg);
}
}


int main() {
    regWrite(UART::STATUS, 12);
    std::cout << "UART 0 " << regRead(UART::STATUS)<< std::endl;
    regWrite(PWM::DCA, 34);
    std::cout << "PWM 0 " << regRead(PWM::DCA)<< std::endl;
    regWrite(UART::RESET, 13);
    std::cout << "UART 1 " << regRead(UART::RESET)<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get compilation errors because you have put a space between the `:` characters. A namespace is named with the token `::` (no space).

Comment: @RichardHodges , I guess the tidy(while adding code) option messed up the spaces. I did not intend it to compile just wanted to display code snippet.

Comment: @Saaras: Snippets don't work for C++. I think it's only HTML, CSS, and JavaScript at present.

Comment: ok, I have it compiling. Question 1 is answered below. For question 2, the code you have posted is using a technique called argument dependent lookup (ADL) where the correct version of regRead or regWrite is being selected because it is being selected from the namespace of the first argument. You can't assign to `baseAddress` the way you want to in modern c++ - the standard explicitly disallows conversions from pointers to integers. Better perhaps to make fakeAddress a `volatile unsigned int*` and avoid the casting.

Comment: I recommend doing away with the register read and write methods -- just more code to debug and additional possible injections of defects.  Access the registers directly by dereferencing the pointers.  And yes, I know that declaring the functions inline will reduce down to a single line that deferences the pointer.  By why all the overhead wrapped around a single line statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation, as a "plaything" will work. Of course, any modern OS will forbid user-mode applications from accessing real hardware, and you need to write driver code, and I think unless you are using Windows CE or Windows Phone, you can't write drivers in C++ in either Windows or Linux (although both implement drivers with a "inheritance style" interface).

To reduce the code duplication, you could implement a base-class  for generic register access, something along these lines: and use classes instead of namespaces to implement the distinction.

```
template<typename T> class RegisterBase
{
 public: 
   RegisterBase(T *location, size_t count) : 
      baseAddress(location), numRegisters(count)
   {}

  inline volatile T *regAddress(unsiged int Reg) {
    assert(Reg < numRegisters);
    return reinterpret_cast<volatile unsigned int *> (baseAddress + Reg);
  }
  inline void regWrite(unsigned int Reg, T value) {
    *regAddress(Reg)=value;
  }
  inline volatile T regRead(unsigned int Reg) {
    return *regAddress(Reg);
  }
private:
  T* baseAddress;
  unsigned int numRegisters;
};


class UART : public RegisterBase<unsigned int>
{
public:
  enum Registers {
    STATUS=0, RESET=1, 
    NUMREGS = 2
  };

  UART() : RegisterBase(&fakeBase, NUMREGS) {}

private:
   unsigned int fakeBase[NUMREGS];
};


class PWM : public RegisterBase<unsigned short>
{
  enum Registers {
    DCA=0, DCB=1, DCC=2,
    NUMREGS = 3
  };

  PWM() : RegisterBase(&fakeBase, NUMREGS) {}

private:
   unsigned int fakeBase[NUMREGS];
};
```

You will now have to "instantiate" your register sets:

```
PWM pwm;
UART uart1, uart2; 

uart1.RegWrite(UART::Status, 12); 
pwm.RegWrite(PWM::DCB, 42);
```

Comment: Too much overhead for me.  IMHO, if you're going to have methods, you might as well abstract and have methods for the functionality and not writing to registers.  For example, "get_status" rather than "regRead(4)".

Comment: I am writing code for an embedded device with 2K RAM and a RTOS.

Comment: @Thomas: Where is the overhead? Have you actually compiled the code to see what the compiler does. I bet anything you like that gcc or clang will produce not a single more instruction in this solution [if you turn off asserts] than in the original posted code. (It will be a couple of byte longer for the 16-bit access that I demonstrate by using templates in the PWM, but that's because 16-bit access requires extra prefix, not because of C++). Of course, if you have a 2K RAM system, you probably need to rethink the idea of using C++, and start thinking assembler. Unless there is OODLES of ROM.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: The overhead I refer to is the typing.  I know it will boil down to a single dereferencing.

Comment: There are obviously tons of ways to "avoid typing". I personally prefer to have readable code over "shorthand that makes it less to type". I do agree, naming the functions better is definitely a good idea. I was just trying to reflect the original code as closely as possible, to show "what I'd done", rather than write a completely different piece of code that doesn't look like the original at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to model hardware devices.
One method is to define a structure with all the registers and then maintain a global pointer to the device:

```
struct UART_Registers
{
  uint32_t status;
  uint32_t transmit_register;
  uint32_t receive_register;
};

UART_Registers volatile * const p_UART0 = (UART_Registers *) 0xFFFFD000; // The address of the UART registers.

//...
  uint32_t transmit_value = (uint32_t)'X';
  p_UART0->transmit_register = transmit_value;
```

Another could be a structures of pointers to the registers:

```
struct UART_Pointers
{
  uint32_t volatile * const status;
  uint32_t volatile * const transmit;
  uint32_t volatile * const receive;
};
UART_Pointers UART_0 =
{
  0xFFFFD000, // status
  0xFFFFD004, // transmit
  0xFFFFD008, // receive;
};

//...
  uint32_t receive = *UART_0.receive;
```

A third version I've seen declares pointers to each registers as macros:

```
#define UART_BASE_ADDR 0xFFFFD000
#define REGISTER_UART_0_STATUS (UART_BASE_ADDR + 0U)
#define REGISTER_UART_0_TRANSMIT (UART_BASE_ADDR + 4)
#define REGISTER_UART_0_RECEIVE  (UART_BASE_ADDR + 8)
//...
uint32_t status = *REGISTER_UART_0_STATUS;
```

It's all opinion.

My preference for readability is the first one.

**Edit 1: Multiple devices**
There are System On a Chip (SOC) out there that have multiple "instances" of a hardware device.  For example, a SOC can have 3 UARTS.

For this case, I created a UART_Base class which defines all the commonality of a UART.  The child classes are responsible for the specific addresses.  For example, UART0 might be at 0xFFFFD000 and UART1 at 0xFFFFD100 and UART2 at 0xFFFFD200.  The differences between the children is the addresses of the hardware registers.

Comment: I like the struct approach, though is it not that the padding could be non-standard ?